# NoSuchMethod when calling AWS Lambda using the AWS Sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I've created & deployed one simple GET API in API Gateway and here is the ARN and there is no authentication whatsoever on this function, I can simply call it on my browser

```
arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX:function:La
```

and the public url that can be browsed using the browser is:

```
https://xxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/v1/lambda/geta
```

and I'm using Spring boot project and the below code to invoke the API (Following [this Doc](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/invoking-aws-lambda-functions-from-java/))

The interface as the lambda service

```
package com.xxxxxxx.services.interfaces;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaFunction;

public interface ILambdaGetBalance {

    @LambdaFunction(functionName="La")
        String getA();
    }
```

The service using that interface to call the lambda function

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.xxxxxxxx.services.interfaces.ILambdaGetBalance;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambda;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.invoke.LambdaInvokerFactory;

@Service
public class LambdaService {

    @Value("${aws.access-key}")
    private String accessKey; 

    @Value("${aws.secret-key}")
    private String secretKey;

    @Value("${aws.lambda.region-name}") // this is ap-southeast-1
    private String regionName;

    public void test() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,
                secretKey); 
        AWSLambda client = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(regionName)
                .build();

        final ILambdaGetBalance getBalance = LambdaInvokerFactory.builder()
                .lambdaClient(client)
                .build(ILambdaGetBalance.class);

        getBalance.getA();
    }
}
```

after calling the getA function the system will through the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.amazonaws.services.lambda.AWSLambdaClient.beforeClientExecution(Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;)Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceRequest;
```

Any idea why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: Please check https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1524

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `aws-java-sdk-lambda` and `aws-java-sdk-core` modules may have incompatible versions. How are you resolving the dependencies for your project? The `beforeClientExecution` method was added to the `AmazonWebServiceClient` base class in version `1.11.106` of `aws-java-sdk-core` - see here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blame/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/AmazonWebServiceClient.java#L590